# How can I implement an auto save that resets if form keeps being updated

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular 9 app.
In this app I got a reactive form. I want to autosave this form to the server after 3 seconds after last change to the form fields.

But I want this 3 second delay to restart if the user keeps typing to avoid the app to send unnecessary updates to the server.

This is my code I use now and it works but it send even if the user keeps typing.

```
this.form.valueChanges.pipe(auditTime( 3000 )).subscribe(() => {
      if (this.form.valid && this.form.dirty) {
        this.submitFormBlock();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe debounceTime is an option here?

Comment: Perhaps! What does it do?

Comment: it does exaactly what you want - delays last emission untill there is no other emissions

Comment: It debounces the changes for a certain time. Read more: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime

Comment: Seems to work! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use `debounceTime` with `distinctUntilChanged`, like that:

```js
this.form.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(3000), // one event every 3000 milliseconds
    distinctUntilChanged(), // emits only when the current value is different than the last
  )
  .subscribe(() => {
    if (this.form.valid && this.form.dirty) {
      this.submitFormBlock();
    }
 });
```